# Duplicate console printf outputs C

Tags: c

I am currently writing an encryption program in C to learn the language. One issue I have encountered is that within my `while()` loop, all of the console outputs are doubled. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char charInput = ' ';

int main() {
  printf("Welcome to Cooper's Crypto Coder\n");
  printf("Would you like to translate a sentence to or from the code?\n");
  printf("(t:to | f:from)\n");
  scanf("%c", &charInput);

  while(charInput != 't' && charInput != 'f') {
    printf("Invalid response, please re respond\n");
    printf("(t:to | f:from)\n");
    scanf("%c", &charInput);
  }

  printf("DEBUG: Input is: %c\n", charInput);

  return 0;
}
```

The issue is that when I run my program, whenever I enter an invalid response (E.g. 'j') into the console, it works fine, but it says "Invalid response, please re respond" and "(t:to | f:from)" each two times (abab, not aabb), which does not make sense to me. What is going on here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Newlines — you're reading the newline after the mistyped `j` and since that isn't `f` or `t`, you're getting the error message again.  A partial fix is to not generate the error message if the `charInput == '\n'`.  You also need to test the return value from `scanf()`, or retrench and use `fgets()` to read lines and process the line.  Remember, you may have expected the user to type `f` or `t`, but the user may have typed `umbilical cord` all on one line.

Comment: `char charInput = ' ';` is too small.
`

Comment: @wildplasser: using `%s` it would be too small; using `%c`, it looks OK.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry, I stepped out at the first offending line ...